# Как правильно настроить работу двух фреймворков с одной БД

Tags: python, база-данных, flask, fastapi

Как правильно подружить Flask и FastAPI, чтобы они работали с одной БД?
Теоретически я реализовал это следующим образом:

- указал одинаковый путь к БД
- в папке models (у FastAPI) прописал ту же модель описания БД

Запустил - и вроде как работает, но думаю, что не совсем это корректный путь, т.к. получается, что если создавать новую таблицу, то придется прописывать это в модели БД у Flask и FastAPI - какое-то дублирование получается...

Есть ли другой путь решения или только так можно?

Comment: Ну, например можно взять и переписать все на один фреймворк, тогда дублирования не будет.

Comment: @insolor, сейчас как раз все на одном фрейморке)) Я как раз хочу разделить это)

Comment: Разделять на flask и fastapi части? И в чем смысл?

Comment: @insolor, на Flask просто удобно писать функционал сайта, а на FastAPI - писать API сервиса сайта. У FastAPI хорошая фича с автодокументированием есть еще, чего во Flask нет.

Comment: Хз, мне кажется точно так же можно и сайт писать на FastAPI. Но в принципе я не вижу проблем в сервисе на flask использовать внутри те же pydantic и sqlalchemy модели, что и для fastapi.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь подружить их так - https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/
Чтобы подружить БД можно использовать на мой взгляд, чистый SQL, через acyncpg например. Скорее всего общая любая ORM в принципе будет работать там и там.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)